# Regex-Match password in mail URL

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Assuming I have an SMTP/IMAP/POP3 login URL like this:

```
smtp://foobar@example.com:abc@smtp.example.com:465
```

I want to replace the password (`abc` in this case) by a constant number of stars (e.g. `*****`) in order to hide it from users.

What I tried so far heavily uses lookarounds:

```py
def starPassword(route):
    """
    >>> starPassword("smtp://foobar@example.com:abc@smtp.example.com:465")
    'smtp://foobar@example.com:*****@smtp.example.com:465'
    >>> starPassword("smtp://foobar:abc@smtp.example.com:25")
    'smtp://foobar:*****@smtp.example.com:465'
    """
    # Regex explanation:
    #  (?<=\w+://\w+:) matches the colon before the password without consuming 
    #  ([^@]+) matches the password (TODO use a better match, passwords might contain @! Check escaping)
    #  (?=@[^@]+$) matches the @ after the server, plus the rest of the URL
    return re.sub("(?<=:)([^@]+)(?=@[^@]+$)", "*****", route)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Unfortunately, this regex has several problems, including:

- The first unit test succeeds, but the second doesn't, because the protocol (`smtp://` colon is matched). I tried `(?<=\w+://\w+:)`, but lookbehinds need to be custom length. Maybe I can consume those URL parts and replace by something like `\1*****\2)` or similar?
- Passwords containing `@` and/or `:` won't be recognized, I'm not even sure of how they are escaped (this is why I don't use the non-greedy flag)

Note that I can't use Python3 (`urlparse` module) -- also I don't want to use third-party libraries unless strictly neccessary.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Python 2 has [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) too. Why can't that be used?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I always thought it was a Python3-only library, but you're right! I'll take a look at it.

Comment: And any password using `@` in it would need to escape that character, using standard URL quoting.

Comment: Is there any way I can directly modify the `password` attribute of a parsed URL? Setting the attribute is not allowed.

Comment: No, but you can build a *new* named tuple easily.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What urlparse needs is a 7-value named tuple, with the other (username, password, hostname, port) attributes not contained in the main tuple-like structure (it fails to unpack them if I use a mock namedtuple). Is there no way I can do this without a custom subclass? In urlparse in Python 2.7 the `password` attribute is accessed by calling a function in `ResultMixing` that splits on demand.

Comment: Named tuples have a [`._replace()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) that builds a new named tuple with elements replaced. I've used it in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`urlparse.urlsplit()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) (which is also available in Python 2); the `.netloc` parameter would contain the username and password (which both would be escaped to not contain plain `:` or `@` characters, see [RFC 3986 Section 3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1)):

```
import urlparse

def starPassword(route):
    parsed = urlparse.urlsplit(route)
    if '@' not in parsed.netloc:
        return route

    userinfo, _, location = parsed.netloc.partition('@')
    username, _, password = userinfo.partition(':')
    if not password:
        return route

    userinfo = ':'.join([username, '*****'])
    netloc = '@'.join([userinfo, location])
    parsed = parsed._replace(netloc=netloc)
    return urlparse.urlunsplit(parsed)
```

Demo:

```
>>> starPassword('smtp://foobar%40example.com:abc@smtp.example.com:465')
'smtp://foobar%40example.com:*****@smtp.example.com:465'
>>> starPassword('smtp://foobar:abc@smtp.example.com:25')
'smtp://foobar:*****@smtp.example.com:25'
>>> starPassword('smtp://smtp.example.com:1234')
'smtp://smtp.example.com:1234'
>>> starPassword('smtp://foo@smtp.example.com:42')
'smtp://foo@smtp.example.com:42'
```

Comment: Yes, you'right on this. The application I'm trying to fix by this seems to use RFC3986-incompliant escaping. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Then you have a problem, because any `@` in the username or password would make such URLs ambiguous at best. The code here interprets the *first* `@` as the delimiter. You could change that to match the *last* instead (using `str.rpartition()` instead of `str.partition()`).

Comment: You're right, the resulting URL would be highly ambigous. I think there is no way to correctly parse it without running into another corner case. I'll try to fix the underlying issue and make it escape correctly. For the record, the project I'm trying to do this for is http://mailpile.is

Answer (score 3):

Use this regular expression:

```
(?<=:)([^@:]+)(?=@[^@]+$)
```

I added `:` to `[^@]`. Hence, this regular expression will match the string between `:` and `@` without any `:` or `@` in-between.

```
print( re.sub("(?<=:)([^@:]+)(?=@[^@]+$)", "*****",
              "smtp://foobar:abc@smtp.example.com:25") )

smtp://foobar:*****@smtp.example.com:25
```

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, this seems to be the solution for the regex version (can't believe I didn't think of this). Overall I think the `urlparse` solution is guaranteed compatible overall (whereare using regexes is a bit of a hack), but your version keeps it a one-liner!